# How to get geolocation api keys without anything

Tags: geolocation, google-geolocation

I wanted to mess around with some geolocation for some testing and needed an API key for that.

I am currently looking into the geolocation API from google/mozillas MLS geolocation. I am unable to enter any payment information for google cloud, since paypal is not accepted and I do not posess a credit card. Mozillas service requires you to request a key with a link to your porject, which may also be problematic since not everyone is able to share their projekt.

So now I was wandering if and how I could aquire a testing API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by using my browsers keys.

In the of firefox you can see, that there is a `geo.provider.network.url` with a `...?key=%GOOGLE_LOCATION_SERVICE_API_KEY%` or `...?key=%MOZILLA_API_KEY%` url. As you can see, we do not get the actual key just yet, but we can completely change the url and extract the key that way. You can now create a [requestbin](https://requestbin.com/) (or use any other methode to receive and log https requests) and redirect the key to your server.

I only got the google key to work, but the mozilla key should also work. The mozilla response seemed hardcoded to give a position of new yourk and an accuracy of 20km.